# How to find the max of td cells in a tree having multiple tables using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to find out the max length of td cells from the tree which has multiple tables using javascript.

for the example below it should return 9

```
<div>
    <p>First table</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>second</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>the</td>
            <td>third</td>
            <td>one</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>

<p>Second table</p>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>t</td>
       <td>t1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>td3</td>
       <td>td4</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

below is my code,

```
function solution() {
    const tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    const count = 
        Array.from(tables, table => table.getElementsByTagName('td').length);
        return count.length > 0 ? Math.max(...count) : 0;
}
```

i have used Array.from here and i want to pass a function instead of writing table=> table.getElementsByTagName directly. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tds = [];
[...document.querySelectorAll("table")].forEach(table => {
  tds.push(table.querySelectorAll("td").length)  
});
console.log(tds)
console.log(Math.max(...tds))
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>and</td>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>and</td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>t</td>
    <td>t1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td3</td>
    <td>td4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getTdTableLength = (table) => table.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
const getMaxCount = (count) => Math.max(...count);

const tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

const countsArray = Array.from(tables, getTdTableLength);

console.log(getMaxCount(countsArray));
```

```html
<div>
    <p>First table</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>second</td>
            <td>row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>and</td>
            <td>the</td>
            <td>third</td>
            <td>one</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>

<p>Second table</p>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>t</td>
       <td>t1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>td3</td>
       <td>td4</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let tds = 0,
tables = document.querySelectorAll(".table");
tables.forEach(table => {
    let table_tds = table.querySelectorAll("td").length;
  if(tds < table_tds) tds = table_tds;
});
console.log(tds)
```

Comment: You can merge `let table_tds` with `table.query...`.